# add a value for a list of specific keys in dictionary

Tags: python

I am trying to add a specific value to a specific key in a dictionary, and I got a list of special keys. I am using a for loop to do this, but the result is adding everything to all the keys in the dictionary

```
keyList = ['a','b','c']
testdict = dict.fromkeys(keyList,[])
specKey = ['a','c']

for i in specKey:
    t = testdict.get(i)
    t.append(i)
print(testdict)
```

The result is this

```
{'a': ['a', 'c'], 'b': ['a', 'c'], 'c': ['a', 'c']}
```

But I expect the result should be like this:

```
{'a': ['a'], 'b': [], 'c': ['c']}
```

Can someone tell me what I did wrong? Thanks!

Comment: To avoid this issue, use a dict comprehension instead: `testdict = {k:[] for k in keyList}`

Comment: `fromkeys` is usually only useful if you use an *immutable* value to initialize each key.

Comment: Oh, so I made a mistake when I create the dictionary... Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line:

```
dict.fromkeys(keyList, [])
```

creates the same list which is shared by all keys.

Instead, explicitly create list to each key:

```
keyList = ['a','b','c']
testdict = { k : list() for k in keyList}
specKey = ['a','c']

for i in specKey:
    testdict[i].append(i)

# {'a': ['a'], 'b': [], 'c': ['c']}
print(testdict)
```